# Eclipse + Tomcat7 pushing not able to copy all files in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am running tomcat7 inside of Eclipse on Ubuntu. When publishing to localhost, tomcat could not copy any of the files. They all showed as "No such file or directory". I have those files, I can see them in eclipse and local directory. Is there a file configures which directory tomcat will copy the files from? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permission thing. Also I recommend install tomcat manually instead of running apt-get.
Either https://askubuntu.com/questions/17223/permissions-problem-when-copying-files-to-usr-share-tomcat6 or http://www.frattv.com/tomcat-can-t-start-from-ide-eclipse-luna-wtp-intellij-idea-in-ubuntu/ will work.